# Add Comment In Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have code but when I write comment not write it , and  error 
"POST /post_list HTTP/1.1" 405 0

in views.py :

```
class AddPost(View):
 def get(self,request):
      form = AddPostForm()
      context = {'form':form}
      return render(request,'add_post.html',context)
 def post(self,request):
      form = AddPostForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('/')
      else:
           context = {'form':form}
           return render(request,'add_post.html',context)
```

in forms.py

```
class AddCommentForm(ModelForm):
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(AddCommentForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.layout.append(Submit('submit','Add'))

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    exclude = ['post']
    labels = {
        'name' : 'Nickname',
        'comment' : '',
    }
    error_messages = {
        'name':{
            'unique' : 'This Title has been used !'
        }
    }
```

in post_content.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

 {% block title %} {{ post.title }} {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}

    <div align="center" class="divtw" style="width: 50%">


                <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <h2>{{ post.text }}</h2>
                <h5>{{ post.author }}</h5>
    <hr>
    {% for comments in post.comment_set.all %}

        <div align="left">
            <h5>{{ comments.name }}</h5>
            <p>{{ comments.comment }}</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div align="left">
        {% include 'add_comment.html' %}
    </div>




 {% endblock %}
```

in add_comment.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="post" action="/post_list">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {% crispy form %}

</form>
```

when I add comment by admin page it comes with out error 
for more info this is [link](https://ufile.io/25gs5) for download tutorial 
and if may tell me what's the problem and how can I save it

Answer (score 0):

The action of your comment form is pointing to "/post_list", which presumably is a listview that renders the list of posts. That view doesn't know what to do with the POST request, hence the 405 error.

It should be pointing to the URL of a view that processes and saves the comment.

Comment: how can I redirect for same page ? because the post_content have a slug and how can I return there !?

Comment: Same way as you redirect anywhere else, surely.

Comment: but how can I take a title in slug ?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: now when user click on post title , the title comes in url like: post_content/<title_name> , now when I redirect how can I take a title name ?